# VBA get the max number based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data in Excel where I have to find the max number in a column so that I can increment it by one. The the numbers are as text like 001. There are also three reference columns I have to consider to identify the max number.

Here is an example of the data

```
A    K    L    N   <-These are the columns 
Ref1 Ref2 Ref3 ID  <-These are the headers
xxx  I    17   001 <-Column N is also text 
xxx  I    17   002
yyy  J    15   001
xxx  I    17   005 <-The numbers might not be consecutive. Instead of 003 jumps to 005
```

Based on the reference XXX-I-17 I have to find that the next ID is 006. Note that the reference is not always consecutive as indicated above.

What I'm doing is first to filter the data like:

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:L" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="xxx"
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:L" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="I"
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:L" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="17"
```

I'm not sure if filtering the data is the best approach, but what can not figure out is how to find the max value in column N so that I can increment it.

Any ideas? Would it work better with formulas?

Comment: Use worksheetfunction.Countifs as you iterate through the range looking up only.

Comment: So unless you need it vba a simple COUNTIFS() function will do what you want.

Comment: Put this in N2 and copy down: `=TEXT(COUNTIFS($A$1:A2,A2,$K$1:K2,K2,$L$1:L2,L2),"000")`

Comment: Thanks Scott. I just need to add one then:=TEXT(COUNTIFS($A$1:A2,A2,$K$1:K2,K2,$L$1:L2,L2)+1,"000"). Perfect!!

Comment: @Scott Craner You should probably put that as an answer, rather than a comment... Selrac -  the way the function has been implemented you shouldn't need to add 1?

Comment: @SteveES only if Selrac changes the question to include the desire for a formula answer, otherwise the answer would be off topic and open to downvotes.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work as the numbers in columns N are not consecutive. For example, from 001 jumps to 003, therefore, countifs doesn't work :-(

Comment: @Selrac try it without the `+1` and make sure that the `2` in all the cell references are the first row in which you place the formula, if it is not row2 in which you first place the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, you can do it this way:

```
Function NextN(a As String, k As String, l As Long) As Long
NextN = 1 + Application.Evaluate("MAX(IF((A:A=""" & a & """)*(K:K=""" & k & """)*(L:L=" & l & "),INT(N:N)))")
End Function
```

You can also use that formula directly in excel after some syntax adjustment, and using it as a *array formula* (CSE). Otherwise you can also use this function as as a User-defined function.

You can also make it faster by limiting the columns to some size (i.e. `A1:A1000` instead of `A:A` etc..)

```
Sub ExampleTest()
    dim n as long
    n = NextN("XXX", "I", 17)
    Debug.Print n ' Should print 6 with your OP's data
End Sub
```

Comment: I can not figure this out. Do I need to replace a for 'XXX', k for 'I' and l for '17' I guess. I keep getting NextN = N

Comment: @Selrac these are parameters of the routine. parameter `a` is what you are looking for in column `A`. similarly `k`  is what you want to look for in column `K` and similarly for `l` (number to fetch in column `L`).

Comment: Please take a look at the test example I added.

Comment: Thanks ASH for the code. I just tried it, but I just gets ones in the debug window :-(

Comment: I tried to simplify it as n2 = NextN2("XXX") and NextN2 = 1 + Application.Evaluate("MAX(IF((A:A=""" & a & """),N:N))"), but I still get a one. Note that N:N is formatted as text. Would it make any difference?

Comment: ASH if I use numbers 1,2,1,5 instead of 001,002,001,005 it works. I'll have to add an additional column converting the text to numbers and then convert the result back to text '000'

Comment: @Selrac I see, it's because (I just realized) that your column `N` is text. I hope that's not the case for also column `L`. I modified to convert it to integer...

Comment: Yes, it is the same for column L

Comment: @Selrac great, it seems to still work if column `L` is formatted as text, provided it actually contains strings convertible to integers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Scott comment I found what I was looking for. In case it helps someone else, with the following formula I can find the next incremental text value

```
=TEXT(COUNTIFS($A$1:A2,A2,$K$1:K2,K2,$L$1:L2,L2)+1,"000‌​")
```

Comment: Unfortunately after looking at the problem I've found that this solution doesn't work as there are cases where the numbers in column N are not consecutive

Comment: I had suspected that already and prepared an answer that does not rely on the data being already "perfect". But I was waiting to see your comments and thought it was...